# List of Token Exchanges Available on Testing Network?

Tags: solidity, ropsten, rinkeby, exchanges, kovan

Found [Kyber Network Token Exchange](https://github.com/KyberNetwork/smart-contracts/blob/master/integration.md) on [Ropsten](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x818e6fecd516ecc3849daf6845e3ec868087b755) so far.

> Please share if you know more token exchanges available on any testing network for trading Tokens as a test.

Answer (score 0):

Trust Wallet was working on all ETH test net until their 1st update after being Purchased by Binance. Then all of the Wallets , Test Coins and Valued Crypto Coins Just Dissppearred ? But Kyber Network is a listed Dapp.